# Magento 2 grouped product import

Tags: import, magento2, product

I'm trying to import grouped products with their associated products, but it seems like something is missing. I'm using Magento 2.1.5

Grouped product imports fine, but it doesn't have any grouped producs associated to it. Where could be the problem?

Using a column : `_associated_sku`
Tried passing values `testskunew, testsku` and `testskunew=1.000, testsku=2.000`. Products with passed sku's exists

Thanks.

**UPDATE**  Just tried using column: `associated_skus`
but I'm getting another error: `Additional data: Notice: Undefined index: attr_set_code in /home/filoform/public_html/vendor/magento/module-grouped-import-export/Model/Import/Product/Type/Grouped.php on line 105`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, cant tell where the problem was, but there is what I have done:
 1. Manually created grouped product
 2. Exported it
 3. Edited exported file
 4. Added my own custom data
 5. Imported products
 6. Success
 7. Thoughtful and confused face of a developer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is Google Sheet for Import - can be downloaded as CSV https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13FemIzzexF5koAdQYjbcKscqoCfXyknYWkQkbSZGPsk/edit#gid=1411519730

[Guide](https://firebearstudio.com/blog/the-complete-guide-to-magento-2-grouped-products-and-how-to-import-them.html) to import Group Products and formatting of associated_skus column where you assign simple products to group

Comment: Incredible link! Do you need your import/export extension for this to be applicable?

Comment: @ThomasHarding yes, our extension provide direct Google Sheet import for all entities, which makes import and management of data super easy with all Google Sheet power! https://firebearstudio.com/blog/magento-2-google-sheet-import.html

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me. Please refer tutorial for full code.
https://www.pearlbells.co.uk/import-grouped-products-magento-2/

```
$associated = array();
$position = 0;

foreach($childrenIds as $productId) {
    $position++;
    $productRepository = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
    $linkedProduct = $productRepository->getById($productId);
    $productLink = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductLinkInterface');
    $productLink->setSku($product->getSku())
        ->setLinkType('associated')
        ->setLinkedProductSku($linkedProduct->getSku())
        ->setLinkedProductType($linkedProduct->getTypeId())
        ->setPosition($position)
        ->getExtensionAttributes()
        ->setQty(0);
    $associated[] = $productLink;     
}
$product->setProductLinks($associated);
$product->save();
```